# How to resolve the following issue: NameError: name 'nlp' is not defined?

Tags: python, csv, nlp, spacy, nameerror

I was going to start creating a dataset for a custom NER model.

I am trying to use the following libraries :

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.training import Example
```

I am not quite sure why this error occurs.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_510787/1444480736.py in <module>
     23 train_data = []
     24 for text in texts:
---> 25     doc = nlp(text)
     26     entities = []
     27     for label in LABELS:

NameError: name 'nlp' is not defined
```

Could anybody please guide me here?

Comment: Apparently you're not the first one to encounter this: [github mordecai issue](https://github.com/openeventdata/mordecai/issues/64) and [github spacy issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2312). You might have to deinstall and reinstall spacy.

Comment: Did you load a language model using the `spacy.load()` function such as `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` before the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it seems like the tutorial I'm following is outdated. If you have this:

```py
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

then replace it with:

```py
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

and try again.